# Trouble installing pygame. Permissions Mac OS X 10.9.5

Tags: python, macos, module, installation, pygame

I have been struggling to find the correct research to install pygame for about 2 days and would like to ask the community to reach a solution!

My MacBook is a backup of my old MacBook so if that is the essence of the problem, I am open to suggestions to fix it!

On the installation front

```
  donners-mbp-2:~ Donner$ brew list
     cmake      isl     mercurial   python      smpeg
     freetype   jpeg        mpfr        readline    sphinx-doc
     gcc        libmpc      numpy       sdl     sqlite
     gdbm       libpng      openssl     sdl_image   webp
     git        libtiff     pkg-config  sdl_mixer
     gmp        makedepend  portmidi    sdl_ttf
```

upon researching I should use this code in terminal to install however I receive an error message following:

```
    donners-mbp-2:~ Donner$ /usr/local/share/python/pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame

    donners-mbp-2:~ Donner$ /usr/local/share/python/pip: No such file or directory
```

Taking a look into my "Home" Directory - AKA Macintosh HD - I have the Library directory within not in my user folder (AKA directly on the main HD).

Should I move that to my user folder then try again?

When running the pygame install here is what is on my command line.

```
    donners-mbp-2:~ Donner$ sudo -H pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
    Password:
    Collecting hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
      Cloning hg http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame to /private/tmp/pip-SqL4BW-build
      Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pygame==1.9.4.dev0 from hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

When executing a file with:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python



    import pygame
```

The error is:

```
     /Users/Donner/Desktop/Python/komodo/pygame/pygame1/open_script ; exit;
      donners-mbp-2:~ Donner$ /Users/Donner/Desktop/Python/komodo/pygame/pygame1/open_script ; exit;
     Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "pygame1.py", line 3, in <module>
         import pygame
             ImportError: No module named pygame
     logout

      [Process completed]
```

EDIT: I did a brew doctor in terminal and received this as the output.

```
    donners-mbp-2:~ Donner$ brew doctor


    Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
    with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
    working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

    Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
    If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems         when
    building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

    Unexpected header files:
      /usr/local/include/python2.7/pygame/_camera.h
      /usr/local/include/python2.7/pygame/_pygame.h
      /usr/local/include/python2.7/pygame/_surface.h
      /usr/local/include/python2.7/pygame/bitmask.h
      /usr/local/include/python2.7/pygame/camera.h
      /usr/local/include/python2.7/pygame/fastevents.h
      /usr/local/include/python2.7/pygame/font.h
      /usr/local/include/python2.7/pygame/freetype.h
      /usr/local/include/python2.7/pygame/mask.h
      /usr/local/include/python2.7/pygame/mixer.h
      /usr/local/include/python2.7/pygame/pgarrinter.h
      /usr/local/include/python2.7/pygame/pgbufferproxy.h
      /usr/local/include/python2.7/pygame/pgcompat.h
      /usr/local/include/python2.7/pygame/pgopengl.h
      /usr/local/include/python2.7/pygame/pygame.h
      /usr/local/include/python2.7/pygame/scrap.h
      /usr/local/include/python2.7/pygame/surface.h

    Warning: You are using macOS 10.9.
    We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
    You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
    Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues.

    Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin
    This means that system-provided programs will be used instead of         those
    provided by Homebrew. The following tools exist at both paths:
      2to3
      2to3-2.7
      easy_install
      easy_install-2.7
      git
      git-cvsserver
      git-receive-pack
      git-shell
      git-upload-archive
      git-upload-pack
      idle
      idle2.7
      pydoc
      pydoc2.7
      python
      python-config
      python2.7
      python2.7-config
      pythonw
      pythonw2.7
      smtpd.py
      smtpd2.7.py

    Consider setting your PATH so that /usr/local/bin
    occurs before /usr/bin. Here is a one-liner:
      echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Thank you for any help/suggestions!

Comment: Can you `pip install` any other package? If so, where woes it end up? What `which pip` says?

Comment: donners-mbp-2:~ Donner$ which pip --->

          /usr/local/bin/pip

Comment: @9000 The directory path is Macintosh HD/Donner/Users/Donner/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip    (here exist: pip, beautifulsoup and easy-install)

Comment: @9000 alternative directory path is Macintosh HD/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages   .    Apparently I have both of those locations with the same exact modules within.

Comment: Did you try `brew install python` instead of the system Python? (It's often a good idea.)

Comment: Consider writing an answer and marking it accepted then to write SOLVED on the top and editing your question

Comment: @halfer I didn't advise to write that, I advised against it, since that's what it was before I saw it. Perhaps I worded my comment wrong

Comment: @halfer just to prove I didn't, the OP wrote solved in his question `20 hours ago` while my comment was `15 hours ago` since that's when I came across this question. What I meant by the comment is "to *consider writing an answer* and *mark the answer as accepted* and **not** to write the *SOLVED on the top and editing your question*"

Comment: Ah, my apologies @abccd, I did not check the timestamps. Yes, you probably meant `instead of writing solved` rather than `then to write solved` - the latter means "subsequently" or "and also" - the opposite of what you meant `:-)`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to the community/layout of the site. Was trying to figure out how to post as the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

This is solved.

I followed this to show hidden files in my $PATH and establish a new $PATH. https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/add-shell-path-osx/

Then un-installed and reinstalled pygame, following the comments here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2jfj1w/how_to_install_pygame_on_osx_1095/. Specifically the comment by redditor PigBoyOhBoy (with some adjustments for Python 2.7 rather than Python 3).